# How do I manage multiple GitHub accounts with IntelliJ/RubyMine/etc

Tags: github, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, rubymine

I have a personal account and a work account on GitHub. Every time I switch from a personal project to a work project, RubyMine says that I don't have permission to this repository.

I go through the dance of logging in to the right account and push again. But then the same thing happens again the next time I switch projects.

How can I configure RubyMine (or IntelliJ/PyCharm/etc) to handle multiple accounts?

*This has happened to me every couple of months for years now and my google-gu has always failed me. I finally figured it out and thought I'd share the good news with everyone.*

Answer (score 1):

The first time that you try to push to the ***wrong*** repository, RubyMine will pop a dialog saying that you don't have permission and ask you to sign in.

It will offer two options:

1. Login… *(this always hangs for me on the JetBrains website. Broken?)*
2. Generate token…

Make sure you are signed in to the correct GitHub account and choose **Generate Token**. RubyMine will take care of the rest.

Repeat the process for the *other* project (switching to the correct GitHub account first).

The next time, you switch projects, RubyMine will pop a dialog offering both accounts and will ask you to associate an account with **this** project.

You'll never have the problem again!

*As I type this, it seems so simple that I wonder why I have had this problem for so many years. But I did.*

Comment: Reflecting on this now, I remember that there is a third option to paste a GitHub token into the dialog. I think, in the past, I always did this option.